# Interactive Bash Script

Tags: bash

I have an interactive bash script which first asks for user name and THEN ask for password and then confirm password again. (It creates users in our ERP system NOT in Ubuntu)

I have an CSV of 1000+ users and randomly generated passwords so I have to create all these users. I want to write a script which picks users from the CSV and then when asked for password it passes passwords from the CSV to create users. Following is what I have done but it didn't work as intended:

```
while IFS=, 
read -a csv_line; do 
createusr ${csv_line[0]}:${csv_line[1]}:${csv_line[1]};done < Desktop/Passwoerter.csv
```

It gives error that password do not match!
The actual script for individual user work like:

```
~$ createuser xyz <press Enter>
password for xyz: whatever <press enter>
confirm password for xyz whatever <enter again>
~$
```

Its NOT:

```
~$ createuser xyz whatever whatever <press enter>
~$
```

It works fine if I add one by one but there are 1000+ so I was trying using a small script over CSV.

Answer (score 1):

**First Option:** Use `newusers`: Its a part of `passwd` package.

```
DESCRIPTION
   The newusers command reads a file (or the standard input by default)
   and uses this information to update a set of existing users or to
   create new users. Each line is in the same format as the standard
   password file.
```

Input file formatting:

```
username:passwd:UID:GID:full name,room number,work phone,home phone,other:directory:shell
```

As you can see, the `password` is provided in the file.

Downside, You need to convert your csv to txt with provided format.

```
newusers < file.txt
```

**Second Option:** you can use `useradd` with `-p` switch.

```
useradd -m -p $(mkpasswd "password") username
```

`-m` Create the user's home directory if it does not exist.

`-p` The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3).

Comment: No, I have an script to create these users as these are part of an ERP and hit various tables in DB and already existing script create user and save the required info in various tables in DB so I have to use this script only to create users.

Comment: This creates the same users, You just need to `convert your csv` into provided format or use second option, and supply the values in `variables`.

Comment: I have to create users for our ERP, not for ubuntu, so first script do that but one at a time

Answer (score 0):

I find out what I needed, my script looks like:

```
while IFS=# read -a csv_line
do
    printf "%s\n%s\n" ${csv_line[1]} ${csv_line[1]} | createuser ${csv_line[0]}  
done
```

and executed like:

```
./insertalluser < Desktop/Passwoerter.csv
```